# Wildfly 9.0.2 Error while deploying app

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-9

While deploying I see in form message `Cannot upload deployment: Unable to parse response with content-type text/html` and in the command-line full error:

```
15:18:28,849 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (XNIO-1 task-2) Undertow request failed
 HttpServerExchange{ POST /management-upload}: java.io.IOException: UT000036: Co
nnection terminated parsing multipart data
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition$MultiPartU
ploadHandler.parseBlocking(MultiPartParserDefinition.java:203)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiGenericOperationHandler.hand
leRequest(DomainApiGenericOperationHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(En
codingHandler.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(Sub
jectDoAsHandler.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(Sub
jectDoAsHandler.java:68)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.ja
va:92)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleReq
uest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleReq
uest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:63)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHan
dler.java:56)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(D
omainApiCheckHandler.java:87)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest
(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:7
74)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use Standalone Mode, when I downloaded new Wildfly server same issue happened - idk if this could be related to ports..

Comment: There is a JIRA issue for this problem: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-1201

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and the only thing that might have changed in my environment is Chrome auto-updating to a newer version. What version of Chrome are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same question with you, and can't solve it now.

But I find a strange thing is that only occur in IE and Chrome,
try to use ***Firefox*** to upload file, it's OK.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: It worked, for now - thank you! :) However I hope RedHat will take care of this issue asap..

Comment: Open a JIRA ;-) Or even better: send a pull request! :)

Comment: What version of IE are you seeing this problem in? I cannot reproduce it outside Chrome 47. Which has this as confirmed bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=567692